# Base constructors must all have the same return type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, react-bootstrap

I want to rewrite jsx to tsx. I have a code that rewrite method from react-bootstrap method:

```
import {Panel} from 'react-bootstrap';
class CustomPanel extends Panel {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
    }

    handleClickTitle = () => {
        return;
    }
}
```

Typescript compilator throw exception

```
 Base constructors must all have the same return type
```

How to fix it? Typescript version 2.3.4

Comment: What will solve your problem (but isn't causing it in the first place) is to omit the constructor altogether. A constructor that only calls `super()` is redundant.

Comment: If remove constructor I have same typescrypt error
MyFile.tsx(2, 27): error TS2510: Base constructors must all have the same return type

Answer (score 1):

Dirty hack for react-bootstrap inheritance

```
const UntypedPanel = Panel as any;
class CustomPanel extends UntypedPanel {
    handleClickTitle = () => {
        return;
    }
}
const TypedCustomPanel = CustomPanel as any as React.ClassicComponentClass<PanelProps>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution: also feel dirty

```
import { ComponentClass } from 'react';
class CustomPanel extends (Panel as ComponentClass) {
   // others...
```