# Subclassing FormControl triggers TS2510 - Base constructors must all have the same return type

Tags: angular, typescript

I was trying to subclass Angular's `FormControl` when I ran into this error : TS2510 : `Base constructors must all have the same return type`

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export class Control<T = any> extends FormControl<T> {}
```

I suspect [ɵFormControlCtor](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/85b5d125be4c689f892c6c50b94c593b85b513de/packages/forms/src/model/form_control.ts#L358) to be at fault.

- What is the reason behind this message ?
- Is there a clean fix (other than what is suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45605058/884123)) ?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgMWiAwhAdjKEA2cAvnAGZ4hwDkAAgIZYDmArvnVAPSloDOVA3AFgAUCICmAD0iw4AYzY8ecTDjz4APABU4AXjgMAngD44kmGKwATJaigZsuAlpMIRIokA)

---

Edit:
Extending the `AbstractControl` does not trigger this error:

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

export class Control<T> extends AbstractControl<T> {

  patchValue(): void { }
  reset(): void { }
  setValue(): void { }

}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgMWiAwhAdjKEA2ANHAIIBGAzrgIYDGMmOe%20cAvnAGZ4hwDkAAtSwBzAK75qUAPQc0FXgG4AsAChVAUwAekWHFoSKFOI1wEAPABUAfHC0x1WACZHyVKHQbZT%20SzYSrVODgwahhaAAsANWp8UXUACgBKAC44ADcIYEdENkC4KHUKdRgk1IysnNY8opho2ISU9MzspCq1FVYgA)

Comment: Blame typescript https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35387

Comment: Please [edit] this question so that it is clearly and obviously distinct from [the other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45605058/2887218), otherwise it's very likely to be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long story short,

`FormControl` [is currently defined](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/85b5d125be4c689f892c6c50b94c593b85b513de/packages/forms/src/model/form_control.ts#L410) as a class expression of type `ɵFormControlCtor` with an interface with multiple overloads for the constructor, not a proper class.

As pointed by Andrew Allen, this is due to TS's inability to have constructor overloads with different types. [(#35387)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35387).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want this to be able to get a typed form value, you can simply override the value on the inheriting class like so:

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export class Control<T = any> extends FormControl {
      public override readonly value!: T;
}
```

Comment: Doing this your `FormControl` is typed as `any` making the typing almost useless.

Comment: You are incorrect. Try it yourself.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgXzgMyhEcDkABAQwDsBzAVwBsCoB6AY2gFMcBuAKFElkTgDFoQAYQhEYmCinSZs+YuSq00AgM6s2bRgA8u8OlWXK4w0eIA8AFTgBeOMQCeAPjhaYjIgBND-KEJFiIEghscCFwYGQARhTAdHAQAG6MUFDA7oxwUIwE7iIUdnDxBBRkjACEAFxw5uzI6uoMRMq6YhI2RIwA7kZ+Zk0ppA4AFACU7Oo0NFUAFsCGs3AA8gDScGx0LQB0hcWMbBOhAHoA-OOT5jNzhhGYANZua5vbJYJTcozKe5Mhx0A Enjoy !

Comment: Helpful, thank you. I now know that by "useless" you mean basically that "valueChanges and others are not typed". This can be overcome by overriding them in the same way that you override value: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgMWiAwhAdjKEA2cAvnAGZ4hwDkAAgIZYDmArvnVAPSloDOVA3AChQkWIjgB5AEY8AplABudKflnEyFalAAeAKz5DBs7aPgBjNjx5xMOPPgA8AFTgBeOAwCeAPjjGYslgAJtaoUBjYuASIgnBxcGDMKsBmcBAK8lDAQWpQsnRB2PiecEr4zLIAhABccE6G8QlJ+ClpGVBZOaV05bLoABYMjLI8NZIy8koqss7eQkSCi4Jm2DzmuITuWLIA7jaR9g5rWUzeABQAlIaCHBx1-cDWj5IA0nDLGwB0ZRU3d3EAPQA-Itbvdns8pHgANaBD5QfDfHoVAZDEZ-eLAoA