# How do you subclass a generic Class expression with constructor overload

Tags: angular, typescript, class-expression

Angular's `FormControl<T>` is [defined as class expression](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/85b5d125be4c689f892c6c50b94c593b85b513de/packages/forms/src/model/form_control.ts#L410) with constructor overload in an interface. This is due to a [typescript limitation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35387).

I was able to narrow the code down to :

```
export interface FormControl<TValue = any> {
  setValue(value: TValue): void;
}

export interface ɵFormControlCtor {
  new <T>(): FormControl<T>;
  new <T>(): FormControl<T | null>;

  prototype: FormControl<any>;
}

export const FormControl: ɵFormControlCtor = (class FormControl<T> {
  setValue(value: T): void { }
});
```

Unfortunatly, subclassing `FormControl<T>` triggers a TS2510 `Base constructors must all have the same return type`.

There is already [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45605058/base-constructors-must-all-have-the-same-return-type), related to this error but the suggestion solutions don't work with a generic type.

So how would you subclass `FormControl` ?

Maybe it's somehow possible to also do another class expression to subclass it ?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgJYDs4hgMwIYGMQIBisAtgMJRoxQA2APACoBq2NArgQLwLYoCeAPgQBvYAgQBnEHBbsQACgBurDgC4EzFSACU6xVCQATANzAAvsFCRYiVOix4CgVyBiMcpTjUaZOLBFiEFBAAdwRGAXldIlIKKlpw03Eg0PDI9Vd3OPoGBAAfQLYaGgFTAIhqXzg%20CBB0mI8vOl5BUwsraHgEXEoJRAzYz1p1F3qsnz9ueVwabAkJaLcBxoYhUXEpGS0lLXUGKP0jEQQLM21S4GnZ%20eIocIRwdBRDa9HB7NXLMyA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is enough for you, but it works if your generic type fullfills all the overloads:

```
class Foo<T> extends FormControl<T | null> {

}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgJYDs4hgMwIYGMQIBisAtgMJRoxQA2APACoBq2NArgQLwLYoCeAPgQBvYAgQBnEHBbsQACgBurDgC4EzFSACU6xVCQATANzAAvsFCRYiVOix4CgVyBiMcpTjUaZOLBFiEFBAAdwRGAXldIlIKKlpw03Eg0PDI9Vd3OPoGBAAfQLYaGgFTAIhqXzg%20CBB0mI8vOl5BUwsraHgEXEoJRAzYz1p1F3qsnz9ueVwabAkJaLcBxoYhUXEpGS0lLXUGKP0jEQQLM21S4GnZ%20eIocIRwdBRDa9HB7LyCotXLMyA)

Comment: Yeah that'll do it, thanks bro !